# In Haskell's Turtle libarary, how to copy a file, but preserve the file date

Tags: haskell, file-io, cp, haskell-turtle

I copy a file with the [Turtle](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.6.1/docs/Turtle-Prelude.html) library. I do so like this:

```
...
    do
        TU.cp oldname newname
...
```

However this sets the date of the copied file to the current time - how can I keep the original date as a shell would do with `cp -p`?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with Turtle. Maybe you could try [copyFileWithMetadata](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.8.1/docs/System-Directory.html#v:copyFileWithMetadata) instead.

Comment: @chi Works! Would you mind writing it up as an answer? I know I asked for a way with Turtle but this is probably the next best thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [Turtle](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.6.1/docs/Turtle-Prelude.html) does not allow that.

You can however use [`copyFileWithMetadata`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.8.1/docs/System-Directory.html#v:copyFileWithMetadata) in `System.Directory` (part of `base`) instead.